# Years of seasons from dates in Google Sheets. Part 2

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is an array with the body part and dates. And a formula that:

- splits it by condition for each body part (the interval between each following date is no more than 30 days) into groups
- and then outputs the years that are within that group (if the group has 1 year, then 1, if the group has 2 years, then 2). The groups are highlighted in different colors for clarity.

> =let(Σ;{1;scan(1;B3:index(B:B;match(;0/(B:B<>"")));lambda(a;c;if(isbetween(days(c;offset(c;-1;));0;30)*(offset(c;;-1)=offset(c;-1;-1));a;a+1)))};
> map(Σ;lambda(Γ;let(Λ;text(minifs(B2:index(B:B;match(;0/(B:B<>"")));Σ;Γ);"y");Γ;text(maxifs(B2:index(B:B;match(;0/(B:B<>"")));Σ;Γ);"y");
> if(Λ=Γ;Λ;Λ&"/"&Λ+1)))))

****How to adapt the current formula** to meet 2 more conditions**?

1. Adding ". Consertvative" in the body part does not affect the group for which the calculation is made (e.g. Mid and Mid. Consertvative belong to the same group)
2. Groups in body part can be arranged out of order in the array
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GLe0fkECDYqBgAunUJvzMA69ki5Du6a1sKbc7bkhwo/edit#gid=0
   [image]

Comment: Also, I fully do not understand the conditions for the colors. Can you provide me more information about it?

Comment: I manage to do a formula that will help you sort the data. However, the only way I could make it work, is by using the table `CURRENT FORMULA` as a helper table, and the data is sorted on a new table. Will that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Added a [solution here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GLe0fkECDYqBgAunUJvzMA69ki5Du6a1sKbc7bkhwo/edit#gid=1813950969) for ya to test out;

I do not have a single formula solution for this use-case here. Helper columns are used to arrive at the end solution. Hoping someone else has a different perspective on this to create a light-weight formula maybe!

***`Cell_I3`:***

```
=scan(;E3:E26;lambda(a;c;if(isbetween(days(offset(c;;1); xlookup(regexextract(c;"\w+");index(regexextract(E$2:offset(c;-1;);"\w+"));F$2:offset(c;-1;1);;;-1));0;30);a;a+1)))
```

***`Cell_J3`:***

```
=map(I3:I26;lambda(Σ;if(countif(H3:Σ;Σ)=1;Σ;)))
```

***`Cell_K3`:***

```
=let(Σ;map(E3:E26;J3:J26;lambda(Σ;Λ;max(filter(J$2:Λ;regexextract(E$2:Σ;"\w+")=regexextract(Σ;"\w+")))));
       map(Σ;lambda(Γ;let(Λ;text(minifs(F3:F26;Σ;Γ);"y");Γ;text(maxifs(F3:F26;Σ;Γ);"y");
                    if(Λ=Γ;Λ;Λ&"/"&Λ+1)))))
```

[image]